# Is there way to compile Managed package classes via Apex or API?

Tags: apex, api, compile

Currently the managed package classes can only be compiled using the link `Compile all classes` link on the Apex Class list view page.

[image: Apex Class List View page]

There are methods like `compileClasses` and `compileAndTest`. But those do not support managed packages I suppose, since Apex Classes could not be read for managed packages and hence we can not pass them. Is there any other way to call the same methods that this links calls to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is: no.

But since managed classes doesn't count against total coverage, I don't think you should worry about that.

Comment: Yes...but performance can be bettered by compiling :)

Comment: added Whatfix Chrome extension to guide admin users through the process to compile application. although this answer did not fix the issue, but there is no in-built feature to do this.